# C simple sorting algorithm to change

Tags: arrays, c, sorting

How to change the following sorting algorithm to operate on a single array arr[]? For now, I have to transfer elements from one array arr[] to res[]. How to preform all operations on arr[]?
Here is my code:

```
void main(){
    
    int arr [] = {1, 14, 5, 18, 3, 1};
    int res [] = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};
    
    int x = 0;
    int y = 0;
    
    for(int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
              x = 0;
          
        for(int k = 0; k < 6; k++){
                       
            if(arr[k] > x){
            x = arr[k];
            y = k;
            }
         }    
      arr[y] = 0;
      res[5 - i] = x;
    
    }
   
     for (int z = 0; z < 6; z++){
       printf("%d ", res[z]);
    }
 }
```

Comment: Tip: Don't just bash code into `main`, *write functions*.

Comment: Are you trying to reverse-sort into `res`? You can always reverse sort by inverting your sort comparison.

Comment: One typically *swap* elements of the array being sorted.

Comment: Search for "in-place sorting algorithms"

Comment: This is *mostly* a selection-sort, and there are *thousands* of examples online that demonstrate how that in-place algorithm works.

Comment: `main()` should `return` something upon exit. See 2nd answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/204476/what-should-main-return-in-c-and-c.

Comment: @alex01011 The `main` function must be *declared* to return an `int`, but it doesn't actually have to explicitly contain a `return` statement. In the `main` function (but *only* in the `main` function) the compiler will add an implicit `return 0` of there's no explicit `return` statement.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Sure I agree but is of type `void` in the posted code.

Answer (score 1):

Just swap the elements in array that mistakenly positioned thoroughly by checking one by one. This called as bubble sort. There's also another sorting algorithms u can search online or check visualgo for animated process for understanding.

```c
void main(){
    
    int arr [] = {1, 14, 5, 18, 3, 1};    
    
    // This applies bubble sort
    for(int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        for(int k = 0; k < 6; k++){
            // Swap elements in an array  
            if(arr[i] > arr[k]){
                int x = arr[k];
                arr[k] = arr[i];
                arr[i] = x;
            }
         }        
    }
   
     for (int z = 0; z < 6; z++){
       printf("%d ", res[z]);
    }
 }
```